# Creating non-rectangular headers

Tags: html, css, frontend, web-frontend

I tried to put image after header. With this image I tried to make header one side bigger, but in another side height: 90 px. Is there any other way to make a header in this shame, or perhaps this way is good enough?

Here is an example photo:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ei47z.png)

```css
.container-fluid.header {
  background-color: #497051;
  height: 90px;
}

.bandymas-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
}

.bandymas-deze {
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.main-logo {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<!-- Header -->
<div class="container-fluid header">
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar">

      <div class="main-logo">
        <a href="/website/mainPage/main.html">
          <img src="/photos/logotipas/Plunges_Olimpas.png" height="120" alt="Logotipas">
        </a>
      </div>

      <a href="#" class="toggle-button">
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
      </a>

      <div class="navbar-links">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="/website/nineNews/nineNews.html">Naujienos</a></li>
          <li><a href="/website/team/team.html">Komanda</a></li>
          <li><a href="/website/sponsors/sponsors.html">Rėmėjai</a></li>
          <li><a href="/website/contacts/contacts.html">Kontaktai</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="bandymas-deze">
  <img class="bandymas-img" src="/AUntitled4_20230721122651.png" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Try this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the header is the same height. But we can use `clip-path` in order to define what parts of the element should be shown.

### Here's an example:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: start;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: chartreuse;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 50%, 30% 50%, 25% 100%, 0 100%);
  padding: 0.25rem 2rem;
}

header>img {
  height: 90px;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: start;
  gap: 1rem;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/393947/punch.svg" alt="Logo Lets Say">

  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Service</li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

### Resources:

Learn more about [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) & you can utilize [this tool](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) to generate `clip-paths` easily.

Comment: But then , how add navbar burgers?